# Form API focus on first input

Tags: 7, javascript, forms

When my form load I would like to set the focus on the first field in the form. I know I can use jquery to do this by doing `$('inout id').focus();`. Where would I put this code so that it only runs on a certain form?

Is there a simpler way?

**Updated**

Using a mixture of smile's answer and clive's comment the code that got it working in the end was:

```
$form['#attached']['js'] = array('(function ($){$(document).ready(function() { $(".form-item-field-name input").focus()});})(jQuery);' => array( 'type' => 'inline'));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can attach js only to your form. Use hook_form_alter()

```
function your_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'my_form'){
  // Add JavaScript file
  $form['#attached']['js'] = array(drupal_get_path('module', 'your_module') . '/your_file.js');

  // Or for inline JavaScript
  $form['#attached']['js'] = array('/* some javascript here */' => array( 'type' => 'inline'));
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried `$form['#attached']['js'] = array('$(".form-item-field_name input").focus()' => array( 'type' => 'inline'));` but no joy

Comment: @user13134 Assuming you're using Drupal 7 you need to qualify the `$` var: (`(function($) { // code using $ })(jQuery);`), see [Managing JavaScript in Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/756722)

Answer (score 1):

To add the HTML5 autofocus attribute from a module in D7, use this example for the user-login form. However, [still not supported on iOS Safari](http://caniuse.com/#feat=autofocus) as of this posting date.

```
function HOOK_form_user_login_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    //should also add JS focus code for iOS Safari
    $form['name']['#attributes'] = array('autofocus' => '');
}
```